# Add an image to a div on mousedown and remove image on mouseup from an array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery's mousedown and mouseup for my art project.

my goal is to be able to down click (And HOLD down the click movement) on one of the four div boxes below, an image from an array will randomly be displayed fullwidth(fullscreen). when you let go of the click (mouseup), the image goes away. so when you click(and HOLD) on a box again, the down click with select a new image from the array to be display and when you let go of the click the image goes away. NOTE: each box will have their own array of images.

the problem im running into is when i click(mousedown) on a box(div), the image that goes fullscreen covers the box/div and when i let go of the click (mouseup), the image doesnt go away. (not sure if that is an issue with the div being covered or my code is wrong?)

another problem im running into is that the functions doesnt fire after the first click.

QUESTION: would using javascript's onmouseup and onmousedown be better for this?

Im using jQuery's mousedown() and mouseup() to accomplish this. the function fires once for one box/div, but it doesnt fire after its been clicked.

I would like my code to allow the user to click on any of the boxes, be able to feed an image from an array (each box will have its own array with its own unique images) and on the mousedown (down click on the mouse) an image is displayed. on the mouseup (letting go of the click) the image goes away. i would like the user to be able to click on any of the boxes/divs, and an image be display. sorry about the html section, my first div is being cut off.

```js
$(".box1")
  .mouseup(function() {
    $("#pasteHere").remove();
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });

$(".box2")
  .mouseup(function() {
    $("#pasteHere").remove();
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });

$(".box3")
  .mouseup(function() {
    $("#pasteHere").remove();
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });

$(".box4")
  .mouseup(function() {
    $("#pasteHere").remove();
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });
```

```css
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
}

.box3 {
  background: green;
}

.box4 {
  background: yellow;
}

#pasteHere {
  width: 100% height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">

</div>
<div class="box2">

</div>
<div class="box3">

</div>
<div class="box4">

</div>

<img src="" id="pasteHere" />
```

Many thanks in advance!
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsyjb7dr/2/

Comment: fullscreen image is not problem?

Comment: the problem im running into is that when i click (and hold) on the div, the image goes fullscreen (Which is the behavior i want), but when i let go of the mouse (let go of the click) the image doesnt go away (which i want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the image element on mouseout event. that will not display image second time.

if you want fullscreen image you would need to add mouseout of document. because image will cover whole document it will not allow box mouseout.

And can reduce code by giving same class to all boxes.

```js
$(".box1")
  .mouseup(function() {
  $("#pasteHere").attr("src","");
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });

$(".box2")
  .mouseup(function() {
  $("#pasteHere").attr("src","");
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
  });

$(".box3")
  .mouseup(function() {
  $("#pasteHere").attr("src","");
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
});


$(".box4")
  .mouseup(function() {
  $("#pasteHere").attr("src","");
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/800x800", "http://placehold.it/700x700", "http://placehold.it/600x600", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/100x100", "http://placehold.it/200x200"];

    var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7));

    $("#pasteHere").attr("src", images[image1]);
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  $("#pasteHere").attr("src","");
});
```

```css
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4{
  width:25%;
  height:100px;
}
.box1{
  background: red;
}
.box2{
  background: blue;
}
.box3{
  background: green;
}
.box4{
  background: yellow;
}
#pasteHere{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position: absolute;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1 box">

</div>
<div class="box2 box">

</div>
<div class="box3 box">

</div>
<div class="box4 box">

</div>

<img src="" id="pasteHere"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4syckb3/

Comment: thank you!!! this works. but each box (box1, box2, box3, box4) will have their own array of DIFFERENT images, which is why i had 4 different functions. is there a way to do that with the code you provided? @Ravi

Comment: do you have arrays in same object or same array? i can reduce more if it does.

Comment: you're the man! im was going to use different arrays. my goal is to run this code locally on a computer and have a folder with images specific to each box. so box1 would have a folder with images in folderBox1, etc. do you think there is a better way to simplify this?

Comment: and yes. you can do it using javascript too.

Comment: How would you do it with javascript? I'm trying to run this locally on a computer without internet?